# Error reading vector elements via a pointer which has the base address of the vector

Tags: c++, pointers, stl

My exe is accessing the vector assigned by dll. I am getting the base address via vector.data(). The problem is that the vector probably has more memory space allocated than required. So how do I read the memory that has the actual data allocated.

.dll code

```
Utf8String ICSClient::SampleMethod2(Utf8String* &p) 
    {
    vector<Utf8String> *temp = new vector<Utf8String>;
    temp->push_back("Liu");
    temp->push_back("Roy");
    temp->push_back("Shanu");

    p = temp->data(); // returns the pointer to the underlying array

    return success;
    }
```

.exe code
// -----p is a pointer that is allocated the base address of the vector

```
while (p != NULL)
     {
      cout << *p << endl;
      p++;
     }
```

it appears that the p is not equal to null and then the exception is thrown when reading the memory that is not null.

Comment: Why not return the the vector? Modifying a passed in parameter to point to something that's been allocated on the heap looks like a proper code smell.

Comment: At the very least you would need to also return the `size` of the vector, but as @super wrote the best idea would just be to return a reference to the `vector`.

Comment: I am not returning the reference since I am not sure whether when the dll is used in the native code will it support the STL.

Comment: I think @Rotem proposes the best suggestion (add a parameter to also return the size of the vector), but if for some reason that isn't feasible (?), can you use a sentinel value such as an empty string to serve as the end of the vector?

Comment: You should also be worried that the mechanism by which *allocations and deallocations* occur matches from the dll to the exe, but you seem to be ignoring  leaks. It is safer to avoid *any* transmission of ownership between dll and exe.

Comment: Got it. "P wont get null by itself". Thank you all. :-)

Comment: Yes I will make sure of the memory leaks. @Caleth

Comment: More explicitly: `new` in the dll may be a different function than `new` in the exe. The corresponding `delete`s may not be inter-operable, and you will have undefined behaviour

Answer (score 1):

`p` won't get equal to `NULL` by itself. Can't tell exactly, because provided code lacks `p` pointer definition and `ICSClient::SampleMethod2` call, but here you're reading array and then you go out of bounds of the array, which is [Undefined Behaviour](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

There is a memory leak as well, since you never free the memory allocated for vector and you lose the pointer to it with the end of function.

I see that you return some code here, which is probably a requirement, so you can't return vector. I'd suggest passing `std::vector` by reference, so you can use it in your function

```
Utf8String ICSClient::SampleMethod2(std::vector<Utf8String>& data) 
{
    data.clear();
    data.push_back("Liu");
    data.push_back("Roy");
    data.push_back("Shanu");

    return success;
}
```

**EDIT:** If passing `std::vector` by reference is not viable option, then you (and users of your dll) will have to deal with raw C arrays. Unfortunately, when passing array to a function, it gets downgraded to a pointer type, **so passing size together with array is a necessity**.

```
Utf8String ICSClient::SampleMethod2(Utf8String** data, size_t* size) 
{
    *size = 3;

    *data = new Utf8String[3];
    data[0] = "Liu";
    data[1] = "Roy";
    data[2] = "Shanu";

    return success;
}
```

Mind you, the user will have to manage memory (delete the array) by himself, which is not really an expected behaviour.

Comment: I may not be able to pass std::vector as a reference since my dll may be used by the native code and I am not sure whether the STL will be supported in the native code.

Comment: I am building the dll on Microsoft Visual Studio

Comment: I edited the answer, but it seems you already found your answer :)

Comment: Since my code might be used with the native applications i was concerned with the availability of vector. Since my application created is in .net. The solution i found was to let the user pass a pointer reference so that when the dll is getting used the dll will initialize the pointer reference passed by the dll user and then the user will have to take care of memory management. No other solution can be possible since the dll is meant for native applications also. :) sorry for late reply @Yksisarvinen